# Press 'alt-x' To Close When prompted

Tags: c#

I need a bit of help. Im trying to get the program to close or restart when the user presses 'alt-x' or any conjunction of keys. Anything helps; thanks.

```
Console.WriteLine("Your User Name is " + userName);
Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("And Your Password is " + password);
Console.WriteLine("");

Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("Are You Sure This Is Correct? Press 'alt-x' To Go Back or 'c' To Continue ");
```

Comment: You can read a key from the console input using the `ReadKey()` method. See duplicate. Note that the `ConsoleKeyInfo` value returned provides information about the key and any modifiers pressed in combination with the key.

Comment: Check `ConsoleModifiers` here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=netcore-3.1